# Android Room Persistance Library - SQlite: debugging gradle error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Just set up an Sqlite db, did my first successful insert, was trying to do an update query in the code when suddenly android failed to compile. Getting this error:

```
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: room-compiler-2.1.0.jar (androidx.room:room-   compiler:2.1.0), lifecycle-compiler-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental.
C:\app\src\main\java\com\example\persistence\repositories\NoteRepository.java:74: error: method update in interface NoteDao cannot be applied to given types;
        noteDao.update(notes[0]);
               ^
 required: int,int
 found: Note
```

The error related to this method in the Repository:

```
private static class UpdateNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void>{

private NoteDao noteDao;

private UpdateNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao){
this.noteDao = noteDao;
}

@Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {

   noteDao.update(notes[0]);
        return null;
   }
 }
```

Data Access Class:

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

@Insert
void insert(Note note);

@Query("UPDATE note_table SET distortions= :distortions WHERE cbtId= :cbtId")
void update(int cbtId, int distortions);

@Delete
void delete(Note note);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `update` defined as:

```java
@Query("UPDATE note_table SET distortions= :distortions WHERE cbtId= :cbtId")
void update(int cbtId, int distortions);
```

So you should use it like:

```java
update(int cbtId, int distortions)
```

When you use it like this:

```java
noteDao.update(notes[0]);
```

Gradle is expecting two arguments. Here it's saying it found the Note object (the one from your arguments).

```sh
    required: int,int
    found: Note
```

Comment: noteDao.update(notes[0]);
This line is in the ViewModel class so those 2 int variables dont exist there. How does that work?

Comment: if i change the code to this:

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {

noteDao.update(int cbtId, int distortions);
    return null;

It wont accept it, the ints just have red lines and the IDE says its expecting );,

Comment: Can you try calling noteDao.update(1,2);? Just to see if it updates your database.

Comment: How would it know which row to update without the pk id?

Comment: You 'find' which row you update with the using "WHERE **condition**". Your condition is " cbtId= :cbtId " When you execute this statement, you tell the database to find the corresponding rows where **condition** is true. In this case, your condition is cbtId being equal to the argument (for your statement it's a variable with the name cbtId). Then when "SET distortions= :distortions" is executed, the part of the row under column distortions is updated. These are all SQL statements, I'd recommend to spend some time studying relational databases: https://www.w3schools.com/sql is a good resource.

Comment: Adding another comment (due to character limit) but it's important to note the distinction between what you are currently using (Android room - this is a wrapper for SQLite) and the resource I linked (SQL). SQLIte is like SQL but is intended for small scale use (which is fine for how you are using it). SQLite and SQL share a lot of similarities but may have some minor differences in syntax. However the concepts will be the same.

Comment: I understand how the querys work what I mean is Im having trouble getting the cbtId (PK) in the first place. After the row is inserted Im having difficulty getting android/room/sqlite to return the PK so I can store it in the cbtId variable to use in the WHERE condition. Atm cbtId = 0 cause I cant get it to return it from the db after the insert

Comment: (Assuming PK = Public Key) If I'm understanding you correctly.. You want to the update() function to return the row number where it was updated? Currently since update() returns **void** it won't return anything. You shouldn't use an **update** statement for getting value from the database, instead use the **select** statement like:
```{Java code}
 @Query("SELECT distortions FROM user WHERE cbtId= :cbtId")
    public int GetDistortionsFromCbtId (int cbtId ); ```